# How do I pass a file uploaded from vue front end to laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a file upload form in vue and want to pass the file data to a laravel controller. The data is passed from page to store fine in vue, but I can't access it in my controller:

vue page:

```
update() {
  this.$store.dispatch('uploadDocument', {
    file: this.form.file,
  })
},
```

store:

```
axios.post('/users/newDocument', {
    file: data.file,
})
```

If I `console.log` `data.file`, I can see the file is passed to post method:

```
'File {name: 'test2.txt', lastModified: 1633600501434, lastModifiedDate:......'
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/users/newDocument', [UserController::class, 'store']);
```

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    return $request;
}
```

but nothing is returned, even if I do `$request->file`, or `$request->hasFile('file')`:

```
'{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}'
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? Do I need to first build the form data? `(new FormData())`. I've tried adding `_method: 'PATCH'` to the form and adding the header: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, but still nothing.

**FIX:**
in vue, pass the form data:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', this.form.file.name);
formData.append('document_type', this.form.document_type);
```

in vue store:

```
axios.post('/users/newDocument', formData, {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
```

laravel controller:

```
$request->get('name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the FormData first and send it though axios Wwthout forgetting to modify the header as you started to do it.